# GCP unable to connect from external ip to service running on VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Attempting to connect to the program (Profit-Trailer) running on VM:8081 inside GCP using the external IP listed on VM instance. I have been attempting to get this to work over 3 days.

My attempt to connect is using chrome browser (external-ip:8081/login)

VM running windows server 2012 with Firewall settings Inbound and Outbound TCP:8081

Service runs on port 8081 on VM, it can be seen in netstat listed on both local 127.0.0.1 and internal 10.152.0.2

VPC Firewall has been set to allow all from 0.0.0.0/0 on tcp:8081

Port scans indicate the port is blocked/unresponsive.

I extended attempting to use a load balancer, configured it and was able to connect from the VM via the load balancer external ip however any attempt from outside IP that's not hosted in GCP it doesn't work.

Any help would be grateful

-I should have mentioned the VM also is listening to 0.0.0.0:8081

Current Solution
1. 
VPC - allow Ingress of all ports to all instances
VPC - allow Egress of all ports from all instances
VPS - Public Firewall - Allow all External ports on TCP to Internal network
VPS - Public Firewall - Allow all Internal ports on TCP to External network
2. Chrome Extension [HTTPS Everywhere] blocks due to ProfitTrailer being HTTP, not HTTPS. You need to disable it, note it seems to periodically reenable even though it doesn't indicate it. It allows you to connect but you get warning you having issues or internet issues so have a pint. 
An easy check is to use Firefox or Brave

Comment: Note: the service should be configured for `0.0.0.0:8081` and not the private IP. Once that is configured correctly start with a divide by two debug method. Turn off the Windows Firewall completely. Try again. If you still cannot access your system, edit your question with the firewall rules for your VPC.

Comment: It was the Windows Firewall, didn't realise the three different ones were running. Thanks, onto the next issue

Comment: @keeny8: Looks like you have resolved the issue. Please post it as an answer (with the steps) so that it would help the community.